# Adding elements to array according to the number entered

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have an 8 element array. If the number of entries is greater than the length of the array, I want to add elements to the list as many as the remaining items.
Example: My array length is 8 and ı wrote to the input 15. in this case how can ı add 7 items to the list?

Answer (score -1):

You can just change the length of the array.

```js
const arr = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8];
let input = 15;
arr.length = Math.max(arr.length, input);
console.log(arr);
```